# Example of a limit with indeterminate form $0^0$ equal to $1/\pi$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm working on a calculus problem and I'm trying to come up with a function that has an indeterminate limit of the form $0^0$, but which actually evaluates to a non-zero value of $\frac{1}{\pi}$. I'm having trouble coming up with an example, so I was hoping someone here might be able to help me out.

To be more specific, I'm looking for two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that:

$$\lim_{x\to0} f(x)^{g(x)} = 0^0$$
(an indeterminate form), but in fact, the limit is equal to $\frac{1}{\pi}$.

If anyone has any suggestions or ideas for functions that could meet these requirements, I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Such that $\lim_{x\too0} f(x)^{g(x)}=0^0$" is an abuse of notation. You can just write $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is in the form $0^0$ near $x=0.$

Comment: Let $f(x)=(1/\pi)^{1/x^2}$ and let $g(x)=x^2$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt[x] \pi}$ and $g(x)=x$, you have:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt[x] \pi}\right)^x=\frac{1}{\pi} $$

Comment: We don't know the purpose of the OP.  But a more satisfying answer might be one that does not explicitly involve $\pi$.

Comment: @GEdgar you're probably right

Answer (score 3):

Take $f(x):= \left(2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)\right)^{-1/x^2},g(x):=x^2.$

Then $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)^{g(x)}=\dfrac{1}{\pi}$$